# @PreAuthorize(hasRole(...)) vs requestMatchers(...).hasRole(...)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

What is the difference between using @PreAuthorize(hasRole(...)) and using requestMatchers(...).hasRole(...)?
Does it have any impact on security? And what is better to use?

I've seen that both solutions are used, so I don't know which one is better.

```
    @GetMapping("/companies")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('USER','ADMIN')")
    public ResponseEntity<CompanyDto> getCompanyById(@PathVariable("companyId") Long companyId) {

        CompanyDto companyDto = companyService.getCompanyById(companyId);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(companyDto, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

or

SecurityConfig

```
.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/companies").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN, USER)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@PreAuthorize` is a **method-level** security annotation as defined in the respective [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/access/prepost/PreAuthorize.html):

> Annotation for specifying a **method access-control** expression which will be evaluated to decide whether a method invocation is allowed or not.

On the other hand, using the [`requestMatchers`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html) is done in the HTTP security configurations (as shown in the `securityFilterChain` example)! In general, it matches the incoming requests based on specific patterns or alike, for example the security constraint of the request having a role - thus `requestMatchers().hasRole()` is evaluated at the time of the HTTP request, before the controller method is even invoked!

- For more complex authorization use cases that involve method parameters/you need to check values before the method is invoked in itself, the `@PreAuthorize` is better.
- For simpler cases in which you only need to secure some URL endpoints based on roles (and there is no requirement to consider method parameters in security checks) `requestMatchers().hasRole()` is easier.

Most often than not, a combination of both of them is useful. For example, a `requestMatcher` to secure general endpoints and then `@PreAuthorize` for more complex checks.